# PowerShell window all black when run as administrator

Tags: windows-10, powershell, visual-studio-code

All I did was run powershell as administrator.

Its black. I can't see anything.

[image: screenshot of PowerShell]

I have somehow set the transparency for it, but that is beside the point.

However, I notice when you right click on the title bar icon and hit properties, (which brings the windows properties), and check the legacy console checkbox, and restart all console windows. This problem goes away.

[image]

But then, the problem now shifts to visual code. Whenever I open the powershell terminal from within (since it is my default console terminal) I get a error popup hinting that legacy console is checked!

[image]

Comment: Is there any opacity/background set in the colours tab?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you ever figured out how to fix this issue, but I ran into the same problem. When I switched into legacy mode to test something and then back out, everything was black as you have shown. I figured out that the terminal colors got set to all black values.

From the PowerShell window properties, click on the "*Terminal*" and then make sure "*Use Separate Foreground*" and "*Use Separate Background*" are **un**checked. Doing this solved my issue.
[image: PowerShell color options]

Likewise, you can also change the foreground and background colors to values that are different. My guess is that they are both set to black.